# Как в VS code добавлять быстро и переопределять equals и hashCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Как в VS code добавлять быстро и переопределять equals и hashCode, добавлять конструктор.
Как добавлять гетеры и сетеры нашел, это лампочка слева кода. Видел в intellij idea такую возможность. Как вот вызвать это "Generate" в VS code.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тег языка добавьте. Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться расширением [Java Code Generators](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sohibe.java-generate-setters-getters).

Доступные функции

1. Generator GUI
2. Generate Setters & Getters
3. Generate toString()
4. Generate Constructor
5. Generate Constructor Using Fields
6. Generate Equals And HashCode
7. Generate Fluent Setters
8. Generate Logger Debug

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. Аналогичный инструмент в VS code.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]